# Interpolating a variable into an XML node search

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to insert a variable into an XML node query but I am ignorant of the syntax.

Here is what I tried:

```
declare @LineNumber int

select @LineNumber = 4

select T.value('(N4/F116)[1]','varchar(30)')
from @ClaimXML.nodes('/Envelope/Interchange/Group/Message/Loop2000/Loop2300/Loop2400[LX/F554=@LineNumber]/Loop2420') Trans(T)
where T.exist('NM1/F98_1[text()="PW"]') = 1
```

The above query does not work but if I manually insert '4' instead of @LineNumber it works. How do I properly insert the @LineNumber scalar?

Comment: sql:variable("@LineNumber"):    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the solution in a comment here's an example to test this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
  <a id="1" value="a1"/>
  <a id="2" value="a2"/>
  <a id="3" value="a3"/>
  <a id="4" value="a4"/>
  <a id="5" value="a5"/>
  <a id="6" value="a6"/>
</root>';
```

--We can use `sql:variable()` to get an external variable's value into a XPath:

```
DECLARE @SomeVariable INT=3;

SELECT @xml.value('(/root/a[@id=sql:variable("@SomeVariable")]/@value)[1]','char(2)')
--result: "a3"
```

--And we can use `sql:column()` to use a column's value (of the current row) to do the same:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeColumn INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1),(3),(6);

SELECT t.SomeColumn
      ,@xml.value('(/root/a[@id=sql:column("SomeColumn")]/@value)[1]','char(2)')
FROM @tbl t;
```

The result

```
1   a1
3   a3
6   a6
```